# Find files named by numbers in order but missing

Tags: bash

suppose the files in a directory are named in numbers, how can I find which numbers are missing?

For example, in the current directory,

```
$ ls
0000.png 0002.png 0004.jpg 0005.png 0007.jpg
```

`0001`, `0003`, and `0006` are missing.

thanks.

Comment: how about try `find /your folder path/ -name 000*`?

Comment: Can there be extensions other than jpg/png? Can there be multiple files with the same number but differing extesnion? etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a script like this in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( +([0-9]).@(jpg|png) )

for (( i=10#${arr[0]%.*}; i<=10#${arr[-1]%.*}; i++ )); do
   printf -v f "%04d" $i;
   [[ ! -f "$(echo "$f".*)" ]] && echo "$f is missing"
done
0001 is missing
0003 is missing
0006 is missing
```

Many thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for his valuable comments below to fix this script.

Comment: `[0-9]*.jpg` is wrong. It will match, e.g., a file named `0something.jpg`. You need `( +([0-9]).jpg )` or `( +([[:digit:]]).jpg )`. You also need `shopt -s nullglob` and an explicit check that the array is not empty. Also, the last field of `arr` can be obtained without computing the length of the array: `${arr[-1]}`. Also you'll have errors in the arithmetic if the first file is, e.g., `0009.jpg` or the last file is, e.g., `0109.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf: All of them were spot on suggestions. I made changes in my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're now using `sort`. The glob `+([0-9]).jpg` will happily sort them out already. But you still have some arithmetic errors: try it in a directory _that only contains_ the files `0009.jpg` and `0109.jpg`. To fix this you need to specify radix `10` explicitly in the `for` with: `for (( i=10#${arr[0]%.jpg}; i<=10#${arr[-1]%.jpg}; i++ )); do`.

Comment: By the way, you don't fulfill the OP's requirement about the extension: files can have extension `.jpg` or `.png`. You need to alter your glob into `+([0-9]).@(jpg|png)` and use a more general pattern to remove the extension.

Comment: Wow that's terrific comment, thanks so much. I didn't know about explicit radix 10 using `10#` I will have it changed for extension.

Comment: `10#` is a standard caveat in arithmetic context `;)`. There are other caveats too (code injection for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
 for i in {0000..0007}; do [ ! -e ${i}.* ] && echo "$i"; done
```

Output:

```
0001
0003
0006
```

Prerequisite: There should be no files with the same prefix (e.g. 0003.png and 0003.jpg).

Comment: But this would to be tweaked based on filenames. What if a filename is `0070.jpg` then this script will also need to change.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer: the key point is forcing an integer as the index of the `seen` array by adding `0` to $1, that by appropriate use of ls and FS is guaranteed to be an integer.

About taking track of the maximum value, the input *should* be sorted, but who knows...

#### *Edit*

<del>`ls [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].* | awk -F. '`</del>

To faithfully take into account the OP request, I've modified the 1st line of my code

```
ls [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].{png,jpg} | awk -F. '
   /./ { seen[$1+0] = 1; m = $1>m ? $1 : m }
   END { for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
             printf( seen[i]? "" : "No file named %4.4d.{png,jpg} in here\n",i)}}'
```