# Applescript: Using Bash to find missing file from sequenced files

Tags: arrays, bash, applescript

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813492/find-files-named-by-numbers-in-order-but-missing), a code for Bash to be able to find a missing file, and this code works great because I wont be able to know the length of the sequenced files, so this is able to find the missing file without requiring me to input the last number in the sequence.

This is the code:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( +([0-9]).@(psd) )

for (( i=10#${arr[0]%.*}; i<=10#${arr[-1]%.*}; i++ )); do
   printf -v f "%05d" $i;
   [[ ! -f "$(echo "$f".*)" ]] && echo "$f is missing"
done
```

And it works in both **terminal** and **iTerm**.

BUT, when used in my **Applescript** it always reply with file 00000 is missing, when it is **not**:

```
set AEPname to "AO-M1P8"
set RENDERfolder to quoted form of POSIX path of "Volumes:RAID STORAGE:CACHES:RENDERS:AE"

set ISAEDONE to do shell script "cd /Volumes/RAID\\ STORAGE/CACHES/RENDERS/AE/AO-M1P8/
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( +([0-9]).@(psd) )

for (( i=10#${arr[0]%.*}; i<=10#${arr[-1]%.*}; i++ )); do
   printf -v f \"%05d\" $i;
   [[ ! -f \"$(echo \"$f\".*)\" ]] && echo \"$f is missing\"
done
"

display dialog ISAEDONE as text

(*
if ISAEDONE contains "is missing" then
    display dialog "FILE IS MISSING"
else
    display dialog "ALL FINE"
end if
*)
```

What I am doing wrong or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLFtw.png)

---

### UPDATE

Seems like the way I was doing it, makes the shell unable to get the directory of the files, If I do manually input the directory, seems like it should work, but now I am getting a new kind of error:

```
sh: line 6: arr: bad array subscript
sh: line 6: arr: bad array subscript
```

Strange since I don't get this error when manually pasting the code into terminal.

I updated the code.

---

Comment: It might be as simple as using the correct shebang. `/bin/sh` doesn't support extended patters, but `/bin/bash` does.

Comment: @chepner no dice, still giving the same error after replacing #!/bin/sh for #!/bin/bash